# How to fix javascript problem in 000webhost

Tags: javascript, html

I developed a website for a school project and locally on my PC, it works like a charm! the CSS and JavaScript are perfect and the website is very fluid and dynamic.

when i uploaded it to 000webhost, the website works well except for the JavaScript. the carousel images, sliders, etc are static and don't move.

The JavaScript is coded into each HTML file using `<script></script>` tags, and is not a separate .js file.

It works perfectly when its run locally and this problem only occurs when i run it from the web host.

Please view the website and assist anyhow possible, it will be much appreciated.

https://dut-it-tutors.000webhostapp.com/index.html

thanks.

Comment: Ok. Open your browser dev tools (F12) and look at errors in console. Should see a "blocked loading" error for the jQuery.js file. Is set to `http` but site is `https`. Can fix by not setting protocol at all `src="//code.jquery.com/....."`

Comment: I changed the path to the jquery library to https and it worked, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're loading the jQuery library from a CDN without `https` enabled. As your site is hosted using `https` the browser blocks the request to your non-https resource because of [mixed content](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/fixing-mixed-content).

To fix this load jQuery from a CDN over `https`.

Comment: Or use protocol relative path...then it doesn't matter if using https or http

Comment: You shouldn't use that anymore nowadays.

Comment: Thanks, i changed the pathway and it began working immediately. thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Just simply check the spellings of the file name.

```
'<script src="./userLogin.js"></script>'
```

is wrong when the actual filename is

```
<script src="./userlogin.js"></script>
```

check for upper and lower cases